# .NET MEF Compose multible Objects

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to find a way to compose parts in new objects. I think the best explanation is an example.

Here is a simple Interface which is implemented by a couple of Plugins. (to be concrete lets say 4)

```c#
public interface IPlugin
{
    void DoSomething()
}
public interface IPluginMetadata
{
    string PluginName { get; }
}


[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
[ExportMetadata("PluginName", "Plugin1-4")]
public class ConcretPlugin : IPlugin
{
  public void DoSomething() {
    //something :)
  }
}
```

Now let us assume these plugins reside in a subfolder of the project so I use a `DirectoryCatalog` to get all my parts which implements `IPlugin`. In this example I mentioned 4 plugins so I would use `ImportMany` to Import the parts.

Something like:

```c#
[ImportMany(typeof(IPlugin))]
private List<Lazy<IPlugin, IPluginMetadata>> Plugins { get; set; }

static void Main(string[] args) {
  var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("Plugins/");
  var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
  container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

If I do it like that everything is OK but I want something like:

```c#
public class PluginContainer{
  [Import]
  private Lazy<IPlugin, IPluginMetadata> plugin;

  public void LoadPlugin() {
    //This is doing different things with different plugins
    plugin.DoSomething();
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
  var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("Plugins/");
  var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
  container.ComposeParts(PluginContainer);

  //Now here I want to have (somehow) 4 instances of `PluginContainer` 
  //because actually I have 4 plugins. Each instance with one of the 
  //four parts
}
```

I hope you can imagine what I want to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand your need for multiple containers.  Can you clarify what your intended usage is?

Comment: It is just an example but I try it. Lets say in the PluginContainer Class are some other methods. These methods stay the same for each plugin but the Output of These methods changes depending on the plugin which is so to say injected by MEF. Better now?

Comment: Please edit your question to include new information.

Comment: But do you mean that you have multiple implementations of the same plugin that can be selected, or that you have many plugins that do different things?  How you are going to use them makes a difference in what the final implementation should look like.  In the meantime, look at the section on nested containers here: https://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ and see if that looks like it might be an answer for you.

Comment: I have tried to make it clear by adding another method to the PluginContainer.
@Steve: The second thing. 

I want to have many plugins which are doing different things but all should be loaded as a part of a (lets say) base class (PluginContainer)
I check the link now. (Thank you for you fast Response!)

Comment: Given the discussion, I don't think that multiple containers are necessary.  Depending on how the plugins attach to the rest of the system, I would just pull them as needed out of the single master container.  You can determine which plugin you want through proper meta data definition.